# "No configuration found for the specified action" in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, struts-tags

I'm trying to learn how to operate with links using namespaces, actions and Struts tags.

I have a simple login form in `index.jsp` page:

```
<s:form action="login" method="POST" namespace="/welcome">
    <s:textfield name="email" label="e-mail" type="email"></s:textfield>
    <s:password name="password" label="Password" type="password"></s:password>
    <s:submit value="Log-in"></s:submit>
</s:form>

<s:url var="url" namespace="/client" action="register"></s:url>
<p>
    <s:a label="Register" href="#url" />
</p>
```

And following mapping in `struts.xml`:

```
  <struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="welcome" namespace="/welcome" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="index">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

    <package name="client" namespace="/client" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="register"
            class="magazine.action.client.RegisterClientAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="input" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="login"
            class="magazine.action.client.LoginClientAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="input" type="redirect">/WEB-INF/view/client/view.jsp
            </result>
            <result name="error" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

The `index.jsp` is displaying, but I'm getting in debug mode is: `No configuration found for the specified action`.

And register link also appears, but it's broken. I saw similar posts and main goal in answers was to check namespaces and syntax issues. I'm a starter in Struts 2, but didn't see that problems in my code, maybe I'm using it in the wrong way ?

Comment: Your link doesn't have a body. The `href` attribute doesn't evaluate its value by default. You don't have `login` action in `welcome` namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was mapping the action with respective namespace

In your HTML form tag, you have mentioned your action is login and namespace would be welcome. Like this,

```
<form action="login" id="myForm" method="post" namespace="/welcome">
```

But according to your package mapped with namespace `welcome` doesn't have action called `login`, But which was available in another package. All you need to do is copy and paste the login action to the welcome package or create the new action with name login inside welcome package.

Comment: oh, this a knowledge. thank you. but would you explain the problem with the link, because it placed outside the form and so have no relation to it

Answer (score 1):

You see this warning that notifies a developer like you that you might use incorrect mapping of the form tag. The messages appear only if you use `struts.devMode=true`. You are using wrong namespace value in the form tag. Change

```jsp
<s:form namespace="/client" action="login" method="POST">
    <s:textfield name="email" label="e-mail" type="email"/>
    <s:password name="password" label="Password" type="password"/>
    <s:submit value="Log-in"/>
</s:form>
```

The anchor tag can generate a link without url using action name and namespace. For example

```jsp
<s:a namespace="/client" action="register">Register</s:a>
```

But if you need to build the url then use OGNL syntax to force evaluation of expression in the `href` attribute.

```jsp
<s:url var="url" namespace="/client" action="register"/>
<p>
    <s:a href="%{#url}">Register</s:a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess issue is with your anchor tag, right? if so, 
try this,

```
<a href="<s:url namespace="/client" action="register"/>">Register</a>
```

change you struts.xml

```
<action name="register"
        class="magazine.action.client.RegisterClientAction"
        method="execute">
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>                
</action>
```

type="redirect" is used redirect to other action ,whereas you are redirecting to index.jsp